# Google Sheets - Assign a script to a button that will paste new data from one cell, to another cell based on a 3rd cells information

Tags: google-sheets, button, lookup, updating

I am not even sure if this is possible and kind of at a loss even where to start.

I am building a database with caller inquires and the resolutions to the calls. Right now I have used a script on a "Submit" button that will take my notes and will then automatically paste that to the next available line on my "Call Data" sheet.

Sometimes it takes a few hours for the resolutions to be completed so I have built it to have a "Open inquiries" tab that pulls the data from the "Call Data" tab using Query to identify lines that have no resolution.

Right now I have to look for the line in my data sheet and then updated the resolution, which then pulls it off of my open inquiries. What I am trying to do is place a "Update" button where I can paste the call notes from the open call, type my resolution in the cell next to where I have pasted those notes and once I press the update button have the script search all the "Call Data" rows and paste my resolution notes to that line (my resolutions are in Column O, Call data is in Column I).

At the moment I am not even sure if Google sheets would be capable of doing this. As you can see I have some basic knowledge of script building and good knowledge of functions but at the moment I am not even sure where to start.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Would it not be simpler  to use just one sheet? Presumably, you have a column for a datetime of the original caller inquiry.  Then add another datetime column for "resolved" plus column for resolution notes.  
A simple filter (which you can save) would then display only inquiries without a resolved date, and these can be ordered ascending so oldest are at the top.

Comment: I have the data on a separate sheet due to the volume of the data. Last year we had over 10,000 calls for my team alone. The other reason for isolating the data to that other sheet is that I have a few graphs and charts on a separate tab that are already scripted to that tab and pull the data periodically based other functions already running for other tabs. I also have triggered distribution emails based on pulling data from that tab as well so it just seems to me keeping all the data in that place is the most practical move at this time.

Answer (score 1):

While I was not able to create the script I did find a work around that I believe is beneficial and just wanted to post it here in case anyone else ever runs into a similar issue.

Instead of creating a button I was able to create a Hyperlink to the cell that corresponds to the comments I plug into it.

Here is a example because I can't actually Link to the sheet for obvious reasons

```
=Hyperlink("Spreadsheet_URL/edit#Sheet_Url&range=A"&MATCH(G35,'Data'!I:I,),"UPDATE CALL")
```

With this I copy and pasted it to an unused column to the side of all my open calls and can click the link and it will take me directly to the cell I have to fill out.